# Call a method in MainActivity.java on event that happens in a library file

Tags: java, android

I included the library [Swipeable-Cards](https://github.com/kikoso/Swipeable-Cards) in my android project. In MainActvitiy.java the **onCreate** method includes something like that:

```
SimpleCardStackAdapter adapter = new SimpleCardStackAdapter(this);

//This should also be done on an event in the library class:
adapter.add(new CardModel("Title2", "Description2 goes here", r.getDrawable(R.drawable.picture2)));
```

Now, in the CardContainer.java (which belongs to the swipeable cards library) there is an event on which I want a new item added to the adapter`adapter.add(...)`. The adapter was defined in the MainActvitiy.java as you can see above.
How can I achieve this?

I first thought about defining a new method in MainActivity and then calling it from my library-class, like that:

```
public void callfromlibrary() {
    adapter.add(...);
}
```

However then the method and the adapter need to be defined static, additionally I don't know how to make this method of MainActivity available in CardContainer.java.

I believe I need to create kind of a listener to check in the MainActivity what happens in CardContainer.java? I don't know how to do this.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To allow `CardContainer` to communicate up to the `MainActivity`, you define an interface in `CardContainer` and implement it in `MainActivity`. When the event occurs in `CardContainer`, it can then call Interface method in order to add the  `CardModel` to the adapater.

```
public class CardContainer extends ... {

   CardContainerEventListener mCallback;

   // Define a interface
   public interface CardContainerEventListener {
       public void addToAdapter();
   }

   // Method to register callback
   void registerCallback(Activity callback) {
       mCallback = (CardContainerEventListener) callback;
   }

   void someFunction() {
       // Event got generated, invoke callback method
       mCallback.addToAdapter(); 
   }
}

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements CardContainer.CardContainerEventListener {

    // Ensure you register MainActivity with CardContainer, by calling 
    // cardContainer.registerCallback(this)

    public void addToAdapter() {
       adapter.add(...);
    }   

}
```

Comment: Hi! Where do I have to  put `CardContainer.registerCallback(this);`? If I write this in the onCreate-method of MainActivity I get the message: _registerCallback is not public in ...CarContainer. Cannot be accessed from outside package_. However, If I make it public, I receive the message: _Non-static method registerCallback cannot be referenced from a static context_.

Comment: @AndiPower What I meant by `CardContainer.registerCallback(this);` is invoke `registerCallback` on `CardContainer` instance. Do you have access to instance of `CardContainer` in `MainActivity`?

Comment: @AndiPower Please perform a null-check before invoking `addToAdapter()` on `mCallback` in `CardContainer` => `if (mCallback != null) { mCallback.addToAdapter(); }`. Also, its best if you register the callback in your activity's `onResume()` and remove the callback in `onPause()`.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, can this only be achieved with a interface or is there a way to do it without the interface?

Comment: @AndiPower Sorry, I'm not aware of other way to achieve it.

Answer (score 3):

please use a Java Interface for achieving this..

declare an interface in the cardcontainer class

```
public interface yourInterface{
        public void  callfromlibrary();
    }
```

and intialize the object for calling the function

`yourInterface object = (yourInterface) MainActivity`;

and implement the interface in your main activity like

```
Class MainActivity extends activity implements  yourInterface
```

and implement   callfromlibrary() method

call this method from cardcontainer class whenever you needed using the object you have created ..

```
object.callfromlibrary()
```

Comment: Thank you sam, I will try this out later, looks promising :)

Comment: Sam, question:
Where should I initialize the object for calling the function? (yourInterface object =...).
I get the error: Cannot resolve symbol 'MainActivity' if I try to initialize the yourInterface object in CardContainer.java