# Dismiss ProgressDialog started by main activity from onReceive of a BroadcastReceiver

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, broadcastreceiver, progressdialog

I am starting a `ProgressDialog` in my `Activity` that is supposed to keep spinning until a called `IntentService` is complete, but when I try to dismiss the `ProgressDialog` from within `onReceive`, the instance is null and I get a `NullPointerException`.

```
public class myActivity extends Activity {

    ProgressDialog progressDialog = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle stateBundle) {
        super.onCreate(stateBundle);
        myBroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver = new myBroadcastReceiver();
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver,new IntentFilter("abc.def"));
    }

    ....

    public void runService() {
        Intent myIntent = new Intent("com.example.service");
        myIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
        try {
            progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(this, "Please wait ...", "Running Service.", true);
            progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
            startService(myIntent);     
        } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Service app not found.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    public void nextStep(Intent intent) {
       //do something when process is complete.
    }

    ....

    private class myBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
    {

        // Prevents instantiation
        private void myBroadcastReceiver() {
        }

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            progressDialog.dismiss();   //<--this is where i get the exception
            nextStep(intent);
        }

    }
}
```

What is wrong with this, what is the correct way to do something in the calling Activity when a service it called is complete?

Edit 1:  Here is the log cat:

```
08-22 17:01:24.497: E/AndroidRuntime(11525): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-22 17:01:24.497: E/AndroidRuntime(11525): java.lang.NullPointerException
08-22 17:01:24.497: E/AndroidRuntime(11525):    at com.example.library.myCoreActivity$myCoreBroadcastReceiver.onReceive(myCoreActivity.java:169)
08-22 17:01:24.497: E/AndroidRuntime(11525):    at android.support.v4.content.LocalBroadcastManager.executePendingBroadcasts(LocalBroadcastManager.java:297)
08-22 17:01:24.497: E/AndroidRuntime(11525):    at android.support.v4.content.LocalBroadcastManager.access$000(LocalBroadcastManager.java:46)
08-22 17:01:24.497: E/AndroidRuntime(11525):    at android.support.v4.content.LocalBroadcastManager$1.handleMessage(LocalBroadcastManager.java:116)
08-22 17:01:24.497: E/AndroidRuntime(11525):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-22 17:01:24.497: E/AndroidRuntime(11525):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
08-22 17:01:24.497: E/AndroidRuntime(11525):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
08-22 17:01:24.497: E/AndroidRuntime(11525):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-22 17:01:24.497: E/AndroidRuntime(11525):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
08-22 17:01:24.497: E/AndroidRuntime(11525):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:858)
08-22 17:01:24.497: E/AndroidRuntime(11525):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
08-22 17:01:24.497: E/AndroidRuntime(11525):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: are you able to see the progress dialog in the screen?

Comment: Yes.  But, then the service being called launches a different activity that takes the foreground.  So, at the moment of the exception the ProgressDialog cannot be seen.  The exception does not kill the Activity, so when I go back to it, it is just stuck with the ProgressDialog spinning.

Comment: so you are canceling the `progressDialog` when the activity is seen again in the foreGround?

Comment: No.  I don't think so.  The dismiss is occurring when another app has the foreground.  It is the call of dismiss is where the exception happens at.

Comment: can you post the logcat

Comment: I am gues that onRecieve is called before you can instantiate your progress dialog

Comment: I can visually see the progressDialog appearring before the error.  Just to confirm, I ran in the debugger and it is created and visible awhile before onReceive is called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a couple of issues.

1) I was following an example and using `LocalBroadcastManager` for registering and sending broadcasts.  But `LocalBroadcastManager` will only work for things within the same app.  I had two separate apps.  So, for example...

instead of

```
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver,new IntentFilter("abc.def"));
```

I needed

```
registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver,new IntentFilter("abc.def"));
```

2) My two apps are built on the same base class which contains the described functionality.  So, app B was getting its own `sendBroadcast()`, but app B hadn't started a `ProgressDialog` app A had.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that for some reason `onReceive` is called before `runService`. Sometimes on Android, a broadcast receiver can be called as soon as it is registered. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16427812/broadcastreceiver-onreceive-triggered-when-registered?rq=1).

Comment: I can visually see the progressDialog appearring before the error.  Just to confirm, I ran in the debugger and it is created and visible awhile before onReceive is called.

Answer (score 0):

please refer my answer in the following link..

you have to use interface for that..it will act as an event listener ...if anything happened in your broadcast receiver you can trigger the interface implementation in your activity

please refer the post

[Call a method in MainActivity.java on event that happens in a library file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25080952/call-a-method-in-mainactivity-java-on-event-that-happens-in-a-library-file/25081270#25081270)

Comment: Looks promising.  I should have time to try this today.